# Change Color of Chrome Address Bar

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome, themes

I want to switch from firefox to chrome, but after having a black theme for so long it's hard to adjust.

Here's what I mean, notice the address bar is still white, even in a "black" theme in the Chrome version.

**Firefox**
[image: Firefox address bar]
**Chrome**
[image: Chrome address bar]

Is it possible to change the color from white to black? If yes, how?

Comment: I looked in Windows Color and Appearance which changed a part of the address bar, but, not everything - http://i.imgur.com/ukGkB.png - If this is not available in any theme file you have already tried, I do not think it is possible.

Comment: Another reason chrome is so fast, no frills, all business.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To the person who says this isn't possible: WRAWNG!

It is possible in Win7, if you theme the OS itself, as chrome pulls those colors from windows. They are not hard coded and since my Win7 is all black with white text, so is my address bar.

Answer (score 5):

This isn't possible. Glancing at [this source code](http://src.chromium.org/viewvc/chrome/trunk/src/chrome/browser/themes/theme_service.cc?view=markup) shows [what parts of Chrome](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/themes.html#images) are themeable:

```
// The image resources we will allow people to theme.
const int kThemeableImages[] = {
  IDR_THEME_FRAME,
  IDR_THEME_FRAME_INACTIVE,
  IDR_THEME_FRAME_INCOGNITO,
  IDR_THEME_FRAME_INCOGNITO_INACTIVE,
  IDR_THEME_TOOLBAR,
  IDR_THEME_TAB_BACKGROUND,
  IDR_THEME_TAB_BACKGROUND_INCOGNITO,
  IDR_THEME_TAB_BACKGROUND_V,
  IDR_THEME_NTP_BACKGROUND,
  IDR_THEME_FRAME_OVERLAY,
  IDR_THEME_FRAME_OVERLAY_INACTIVE,
  IDR_THEME_BUTTON_BACKGROUND,
  IDR_THEME_NTP_ATTRIBUTION,
  IDR_THEME_WINDOW_CONTROL_BACKGROUND
};
```

You can see that the address box isn't present in the list and consequently, cannot be changed.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it can be done via OS itself. On Windows 7 you can do via "Windows color and appearance" window by selecting "Window" option:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Chrome themes don't affect the address bar, it's the windows theme settings that affect it.

Change the colors in your windows theme via control panel>Appearance>Personalization>Window Color

The colors that affect the address bar are the "Window" colors, so the background will match the window background color and the font color will match the text color.

After you've changed the windows settings, you have to close chrome and reopen.

Answer (score 0):

You could try browsing the [Chrome Themes](https://chrome.google.com/webstore?hl=en&category=theme), you might not be able to reproduce the Firefox theme exactly but should be able to find something close.

Answer (score 0):

Changing the windows theme in windows 7 no longer changes the address bar color, and more recently the flag to revert Chrome's UI layout has gone. It seems the only fix is a third party program like Custom Desktop Logo or Rainmeter, or else you'll have to rely on Chrome. I can confirm Custom Desktop Logo works just fine if you want something very simple and don't mind losing some readability.

I'm not saying it's ideal, here are the steps:

1. Download Custom Desktop Logo from the [official site](http://customdesktoplogo.wikidot.com/download). Extract all files.
2. Take a screenshot of your address bar (remember it changes size if you add extensions to the toolbar, etc. so you may want to do multiple versions)
3. Paste the screenshot to your image editor of choice (even MS paint), crop the address bar and make the desired changes - opacity can be changed later. Leave the areas outside of the border a different color. Save as .png.
4. Go to [onlinepngtools.com](https://onlinepngtools.com/create-transparent-png) to make the areas outside of the border transparent. Save the image in a memorable folder.
5. Open CustomDesktopLogo.exe, right-click the tray icon then go to Settings and Change Image Folder to your memorable folder. You can also change opacity via Animations/Graphics. Finally, go to Location, click on Display at Location Offset and set the X and Y values - for a 1920*1080 monitor X=129 Y=46 should work.
6. Done!